# Performance issue with LINQ when getting recent data by hours on a large set

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic `List<T> ticker` collection where `T` object has, amongst others, property `AsOfDate` which is `DateTime`.
This list collection can have >20k items.

I am getting the most recent hours from the `AsOfDate`, where the amount is specified by a variable `amount` of type `int` (e.g. 3)

My code is:

```
from x in ticker
let y = ticker.OrderByDescending(y => x.AsOfDate).First()
where x.AsOfDate > y.AsOfDate.AddHours(-amount)
orderby x.AsOfDate descending
select x).ToList();
```

When working with a small dataset (say 200 items in list), this works fine. However, when working with over 20,000 items in the list, I am witnessing significant speed issues (3 minutes).

Why is the LINQ query taking so long? And how can I improve it?

Comment: "I have a non-generic List<T> ticker" NON-generic? are you sure?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk - sorry "generic".

Comment: For every single ticker, you are ordering the entire list.

Comment: The line `let y = ticker.OrderByDescending(y => x.AsOfDate).First()` doesn't make sense. Getting `x.AsOfDate` is going to be the same value regardless of `y`. And you're overloading the definition of `y`.

Comment: Consider using `OrderBy` then `TakeWhile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by pre-fetching `y`:

```
var dateLimit = ticker
    .OrderByDescending(y => x.AsOfDate)
    .First().AsOfDate.AddHours(-amount);

var result =(
    from x in ticker
    where x.AsOfDate > dateLimit
    orderby x.AsOfDate descending
    select x
).ToList();
```

Currently, you keep re-evaluating `y` in each iteration, which requires sorting for the overall time efficiency of O(n<sup>2</sup>log<sub>2</sub>n).

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight for the comments. slight mistake in your snippet, but its fine as your comments have sent me in the right direction.